# Failed to use N[%] for a infinite series

Tags: evaluation, series-expansion, summation

I am trying to evaluate a infinite series:
$$
2 \sum _{l=1}^{\infty } \Re\left(n^{\frac{2 i \pi  l}{\log (q)}} \Gamma \left(\alpha -\frac{2 i l \pi }{\log (q)}\right)\right)
$$
With the code:

```
delta[\[Alpha]_, q_, n_] = 
 2 Sum[Re[Gamma[\[Alpha] - I 2 l \[Pi]/Log[q]] Exp[
      I 2 l \[Pi] Log[n]/Log[q]]], {l, 1, Infinity}]
delta[1,10,10]
N[%]
```

But Mathematica complaints:

```
NSum::nsnum: Summand (or its derivative) ((0. +3.14159 I) 2.^(1. +(0. +2.72875 I) l) 5.^((0. +2.72875 I) l) Gamma[1. -(0. +2.72875 I) l]-(0. +1.36438 I) 2.^(1. +(>) l) > Gamma[1. -(0. +>) l] PolyGamma[0.,1. -(0. +2.72875 I) l]) > is not numerical at point l = 16.
```

Please help me to evaluate it or explain the problem, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Mathematica 10.0.2.0, I do not receive the error message you did.  However, `Sum` returns unevaluated, which happens when `Sum` cannot do the summation.  Since you are seeking a numerical answer, I suggest that you use a large upper bound on your `Sum` instead of `Infinity`.  For instance,

```
delta[\[Alpha]_, q_, n_] := 2 Sum[Re[Gamma[\[Alpha] - I 2 l \[Pi]/Log[q]] 
    Exp[I 2 l \[Pi] Log[n]/Log[q]]], {l, 1, 100}];
N[delta[1, 10, 10]]
(* 0.0818184 *)
```

Incidentally, I tried `NSum` instead, but it did not return an answer in a reasonable time.

Comment: Thank you for trying the code. Maybe I am too greed to let Mathematica to compute the infinite sum. You're right, I am trying a bigger upper bound now. By the way, I am using Mathematica 9.0.1.0 Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[delta]

delta[\[Alpha]_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ, n_?NumericQ] :=
  Module[
   {z = I 2.0` l \[Pi]/Log[q]},
   Re[2 NSum[Gamma[\[Alpha] - z] n^z,
      {l, 1, Infinity}]]];

delta[1, 10, 10]
```

> 0.0818184

Comment: It does work! And produce the answer in a reasonable time,While The code of @bbgodfrey did not. But why is the use of Module accelerate the calculation of Nsum? Because the compact expression with local variable z?

Comment: The compact form (reuse of sub calculation of local variable `z`) helps to speed the calculation up; however, the major cause of the speed up is doing the calculation with approximate real numbers rather than exact numbers and using `NSum` rather than `Sum`.